# C# Sending gmail with uploading large file on Google drive attachment

Tags: c#, google-drive-api, gmail, gmail-api

I need to create a program in c# that can upload to google drive and attach it to email(gmail) and send it to recipients. The file is more than 50mb that is why we need google drive to send. Is there a google api available to do those task all in one? Is that possible? I have been reading solutions here but mostly uploading file to google drive and sending email are separate solutions and I am having a hard time combining those two task. Can somebody direct me if there is a proper code or api to do those task.

The program will provide the following information

sender email: username

sender email: password

upload directory and file

recipient or email receiver

Comment: A quick check of google drive api came up with this: https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/quickstart/dotnet

Comment: Welcome to stack please do some research make an attempt and come back ifyou have any issues.   We are not here to tell you what is possible and what is not possible.  you may want to read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: You can write a program that first uploads a file to Drive with the Drive API (see quckstart link provided by @MarkMcWhirter, subsequently you url base encode the file and send it with th Gmail API as attachment: https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/guides/uploads I suggest you at least try to write a code yourself. If you provide a code snippet and explain where you got stuck, you are likely to receive some support.

Comment: Thank you for the feed back. Sorry if my question is a little too vague or spoon feed. I am just having trouble where to start, I am not asking for code cause i can can study and make it in the long run. I'm just asking if somebody can direct me where to start. What api to use and if the api capable if solving my problem. The answer of Mark McWhirter gave me an idea where to start. An answer that I needed. But if you can add more I would gladly accept. I will turn down this question if it will cause too much trouble but as long as i can have an idea where to start then Thank you

Comment: Are you still working on this? How do you want to attach the uploaded file to Gmail's mail? Do you want to add a link in the mail so the recipient can download the file? Is the Google Drive part necessary if you can just add an attachment in the mail directly (so skipping the complexity of using Google Drive API)? Does the user of the program provide the e-mail address of the recipients (in the gmail)? Just a note, you need to be much more specific in giving instructions. Type step-by-step what should the program do.

Comment: Yes i am still working on this. Still studying the link the first comment sent. My scenario is i have a system that creates a back up and sends to the administrator via email. The zip back up is 50mb above so uploading via email attachment cant solve the problem. So i needed google drive for that. The program will provide the email. Thank you for the attention for my

Comment: I see, didn't know that there is a limit for the attachment. Would sending a downloadable link in the e-mail work for you? So the recipient can click on the link and download it via Google Drive?

Comment: I'm going to wait until tomorrow for your answer. I have created a program that you've asked for. I had to make some changes though. When the file is uploaded, the user of the program gets the public downloadable link for it, then he's able to copy it and paste it into the text field of an e-mail. I will post it tomorrow on GitHub and on here as an answer. Hopefully, you will be able to learn something from it :)

Comment: @GoodNickName woah.youre a life saver sir. I never thought of that. I thought that the actual item in google drive is just an attachment of gmail. That is what im trying to make. And now i think my reasoning logic solution is wrong. Now that you mention Public link of google drive, i realized that google drive isn't attaching the item on email. Instead it provides a public link that can be shared via email. Thanks to your idea i now have know what solution i will try to create. The missing link in my idea is the public. Thank you very much sir. Atleast the solution is starting to become clear.

Comment: I also thought that since google drive and gmail is owned by a single company then then the process should be automatic which makes my desired solution wrong. Instead you gave me a proper picture of what the solution should be and I thank you for that.

Comment: Please do share you're program sample that you have created so that i can study it more. I will also choose it as my answer. It will kick start my knowledge while studying your code. Don't worry i am not that kind of developer that will ask for a spoon feed solution and will just copy paste it. I will study that provided code and will implement it on my own.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Mandz Yeah, I'm not sure if there is an automatic way of attaching the file to the Gmail's e-mail, however, the way Gmail handles links is quite interesting:
[image]

As you can see, it attaches the link to the attachment, making it in some way automatic.
Here's the link to the GitHub repository:
[link](https://github.com/Coke21/E-Mail-Sender)

I've decided to make it GUI using WPF and MVVM pattern (using Caliburn.Micro). Hopefully, it won't be too difficult to run the sample app on your end.
Here are the steps that you need to do in order to run the app:

1. Have a Google account.
2. Login into https://console.developers.google.com/ (It is a platform where you handle all your tokens etc.)
3. Create a new project - top left, click on Select a project, new window should appear, click on New Project, name it whatever you want, when that's done, click on Navigation menu (top left), APIs & Services -> Library, Search for Google Drive and Gmail API, enable them both. Then go to Credentials (In APIs & Services), click Create credentials, choose OAuth client ID, you might need to configure consent screen (but I think it's pretty easy, you have to choose either Internal or External and provide the Application Name), in Create OAuth client ID, choose Other, name it whatever you want, Click Ok on the new window, then Download JSON on Credentials Page (on the right), place the file in the same dictionary where the .exe app is. Then create another credential for Gmail token (the same way as above I believe). Place it again in the same dictionary where the .exe app is.
4. To run the app, you will need .NET Core 3.1 https://dotnet.microsoft.com/download (or just new version of Visual Studio)
5. Build the app, Click the Choose button to select a file, then Click Upload button.
6. **If the tokens are in the same dictionary**, a new website should launch and ask you to log in to an appropriate account (I would choose the same Gmail account where you created these tokens) then if you give access to this app, agree to that. When that's done, a token folder should appear in the same dictionary as the .exe file. The reason why the token folder is created is so you won't have to repeat the 6th step.
7. A downloadable link should appear, copy it and paste in the Text field in the E-Mail tab.
8. Type the E-mail address (I would suggest your alt account or something so you can just test it).
9. A subject field can be empty.
10. Click Send-Email (now just redo the 6th step)

Some side notes:

1. I had to create two tokens, for Drive and Gmail APIs, I dunno if it's the quickest way of doing this, I tried to just use 1 token but it didn't want to work.
2. MainView.xaml is just the things that you see, so it doesn't really matter in this case.
3. MainViewModel.cs is the file where all the important things for you are.
4. I would look at `UploadFileAsync` method, it does upload to the `root` folder (the main folder of Google Drive), then puts the file to the public so anyone can access the file and download it, then gets the public link to the file.
5. `SendEmail` method sends the E-Mail.
6. I put these methods asynchronous so the app won't just freeze (hopefully it won't be a problem for you).
7. The code is not perfect but I think it will do as learning material.

Feel free to post any questions about it, below. Good luck.

Edit: If you want [link like this](https://www.youtube.com/) instead of full link, you change in string `plainText` to `"<p><a href=\"https://www.youtube.com/\">test</a><p>"`

Comment: Wow this is a very good answer. It might force me to study additional knowledge such as mvvm (a technology that doesn't appear on a solo developer with no any external help except forums). although it might take a while for me to understand everything i really want to thank you. Not only you gave me the core idea but you also gave me new things to study. I can't wait to sink my teeth on this topic after the holidays

Comment: sorry if i cant still accept this as an answer just yet because i haven't tested it. but rest assure that i will accept it as soon as i can make it working on my machine so that we be sure that the answer is fully correct for future developers

Comment: No problem :) Yeah, take your time as this is not something that may be appropriate for new people. MVVM is just a pattern of how should one write their GUI apps. I learned MVVM from Tim Corey https://youtu.be/laPFq3Fhs8k but if you're new to WPF I would just advise you to learn without MVVM. Feel free to post any questions and problems so hopefully, I will be able to help you :>